# Laravel Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #2 [ <required>

Tags: laravel, array, composer, component

Estoy haciendo una web en Laravel con un listado de películas donde puedes seleccionar qué películas te gustan. Para ello, en cada película tendría un botón para "Añadir a favoritos" y en caso de que ya se tiene la película como favorita aparecería el botón "Ya no me gusta".

He aquí el array $FavoriteMovies donde contiene las películas favoritas:

```
array:7 [▼
  8392 => 8392
  414906 => 414906
  823625 => 823625
  505026 => 505026
  614917 => 614917
  629542 => 629542
  335787 => 335787
]
```

Aquí el fragmento del código donde aparecerían dichos botones:

```
@if($FavoriteMovies[$movie['id']] == $movie['id'])
    <form action="{{route('components.dislike', $movie['id'])}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
        <input type="hidden" id="id_user" name="id_user" value="{{$iduser = auth()->id()}}">
        <input type="hidden" id="id_movie" name="id" value="{{$idmovie = $movie['id']}}">
        <button type="submit">
            <span>Dislike</span>
        </button>
    </form>
    @else
    <form action="{{route('components.favorite', $movie['id'])}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
        <input type="hidden" id="id_user" name="id_user" value="{{$iduser = auth()->id()}}">
        <input type="hidden" id="id_movie" name="id" value="{{$idmovie = $movie['id']}}">
        <button type="submit">
            <span>Add favorite</span>
        </button>
    </form>
@endif
```

Añado $FavoriteMovies en el componente de la vista:

```
<x-movie-card :movie="$movie" :genres="$genres" :FavoriteMovies="$FavoriteMovies"/>
```

Hasta aquí, el código no hace ningún efecto. Por lo que añado $FavoriteMovies en este fragmento de código:

```
namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class MovieCard extends Component
{
    public $movie;
    public $genres;
    public $FavoriteMovies;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($movie, $genres, $FavoriteMovies)
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;
        $this->genres = $genres;
        $this->FavoriteMovies = $FavoriteMovies;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.movie-card');
    }
}
```

Pero me sale este mensaje de error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #2 [ <required> $FavoriteMovies ]] in class App\View\Components\MovieCard (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/filments/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Versión corta:

Como dice en [Blade Templates: Casing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#casing) .

> Component constructor arguments should be specified using camelCase,
> while kebab-case should be used when referencing the argument names in
> your HTML attributes.

O sea: atributos con guión, variables en camelCase

```
<x-movie-card :movie="$movie" :genres="$genres" :favorite-movies="$favoriteMovies"/>
```

Asegúrate de renombrar `$favoriteMovies` en el resto del código, y lo mismo con el atributo de instancia del componente.

```
class MovieCard extends Component
{
    public $movie;
    public $genres;
    public $favoriteMovies;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($movie, $genres, $favoriteMovies)
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;
        $this->genres = $genres;
        $this->favoriteMovies = $favoriteMovies;
    }
```

A lo mejor funcionaría igual si usaras `$this->FavoriteMovies = $favoriteMovies` pero mejor ahórrate el sufrimiento de debuggear esa mezcla.

#### Versión Larga

**1.** Las variables en PHP son case-sensitive. Pero [la especificación HTML es case insensitive para tags y atributos](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity). así que por naturaleza los siguientes son idénticos:

```
<x-movie-card :FavoriteMovies="$FavoriteMovies" />
<x-movie-card :fAvOrItesMovieS="$FavoriteMovies" />
<x-movie-card :FAVORITEMOVIES="$FavoriteMovies" />
```

Blade permite salirse un poco de esa rigidez pero no le conviene apartarse del estándar HTML cuando Blade no pretende reemplazarlo.

**2.** Similarmente a la manera como [Element.dataset normaliza sus data attributes en HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#name_conversion), Blade normaliza el nombre de éstos a camelCase, para generar un parameterBag. Un tag como este:

```
<x-movie-card :FavoriteMovies="$FavoriteMovies" :favorite-movies="$favoriteMovies"/>
```

Se almacena a un objeto similar a un array

```
 'favoriteMovies' => $FavoriteMovies
 'favoriteMovies' => $favoriteMovies
```

En donde se pisan los nombres que al normalizase se han vuelto repetidos.

**3.** La especificación W3C no establece un orden para los atributos, de manera que

```
<x-movie-card :movie="$movie" :genres="$genres" :favorite-movies="$favoriteMovies"/>
```

Debe generar el mismo resultado que

```
<x-movie-card :favorite-movies="$favoriteMovies" :movie="$movie" :genres="$genres" />
```

**4.** Para permitir pasarle atributos en cualquier orden al componente, Blade usa ReflectionClass para hacer introspección del constructor. Léase "*agarra los nombres de los parámetros de __construct*".

Estas variables cuyo nombre ahora conoce, las va poblando con el parameter bag. Y en eso se da cuenta que tiene un parameter `favoriteMovies` que no ha pedido, pero no tiene `FavoriteMovies` que le falta porque en la normalización el parameter bag lo ha eliminado.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!!